# How to remove an integer pattern from filename using unix command

Tags: shell, unix, rename

I've bunch of mp3 files that has track number prefixed. For eg:

> 01 - MovieName - SongNameA.mp3
>
> 02 - MovieName - SongNameB.mp3

I need to search and remove the track number and hyphen sign from the file name.

I tried using find and grep and I couldn't find a query to pipe with mv command to rename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using shell

```
for f in [[:digit:]][[:digit:]]' - '*mp3; do mv -i -- "$f" "${f#?????}"; done
```

Or, the same thing but written as multiple lines:

```
for f in [[:digit:]][[:digit:]]' - '*mp3
do
    mv -i -- "$f" "${f#?????}"
done
```

The glob `[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]' - '*mp3` matches the files that you are interested in.  `mv "$f" "${f#?????}"` removes the first five characters of their name.  The `-i` option to `mv` tells it to ask before overwriting an existing file.

#### Using the Perl' rename utility

```
rename 's/^\d\d - //' *mp3
```

This looks at all `.mp3` files and, if their name begins with two digits, followed by space, followed by a dash, followed by space, then those characters are removed.

`rename` will refuse to overwrite an existing file unless you provide the `-f` option.

This section refers to Perl's `rename` utility.  Note that some linux distributions come with a different and incompatible `rename` utility installed by default.  Sometimes, the perl `rename` utility is available under the name `prename`.

Comment: And what happens with two files named `01 - MovieName - SongNameA.mp3` and `02 - MovieName - SongNameA.mp3`?

Comment: @dfogni they are renamed now :)